# Location of Ubuntu HP Printer Driver

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp

I saw a on the HP website that they have printer drivers for Ubuntu machines.  I have tried to find a driver for my HP printer and I have not had much success.  Can anyone point me to where I could download the 32-bit x86 Ubuntu 12.04 driver for a HP C4200 printer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Connect the printer to your Ubuntu computer and it will automatically work**

This is because 12.04+ already comes with the latest version of all HP printing and scanning drivers for Ubuntu (The [hiplip-gui](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hplip-gui) [image: Install hplip-gui] package). Just plug the Printer to the computer, turn it on and done. You can access the printer by opening the Dash and typing **Printers**.

Additionally I have a HP Photosmart C3100 and a Photosmart C4200 (The C4250 model just in case) and even if you go to the HP website, after selecting in their menu your model, you will be greeted with this:

[image]

Which just means that Ubuntu supports your Printer out of the box. There is no need to install anything else (This is not Windows just in case you think they work the same in this aspect). So it saves you and me a lot of time to not worry about drivers. Specially those huge ones that HP has for each printer.